# Unwinding struct pointer parameter to local variables in function

Tags: c, function, struct

I want to ask you about some idea, which came to my mind while programming. Before for loop i create new local variables to hold all struct variables to improve readability and performance. This is the sample code:

```
#define PI 3.14

typedef struct{

    double var1;
    double var2;
    double var3;
    double var4;
}MyStruct1;

typedef struct{

    double var1;
    double var2;
    double var3;
}MyStruct2;

double* Foo(const MyStruct1* const struct1, const MyStruct2* const struct2){

    const int size = 10000; 
    double* arr = (double*)calloc(size*5, sizeof(double));
    if(!arr)
        return NULL;

    const double a = struct1->var1;
    const double b = struct1->var2;
    const double c = struct1->var3;
    const double d = struct1->var4;

    const double e = struct2->var1;
    const double f = struct2->var2;
    const double g = struct2->var3;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
        arr[i]          = -a*pow(b,2.0)*c*d;
        arr[i + size]   = 2.0*a*b*c*2.0*PI*g*f;
        arr[i + 2*size] = -2.0*Pi*a*g*d;
        arr[i + 3*size] = -a*g;
        arr[i + 4*size] = b;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

First of all if i don't use local variables to hold struct1 values my 
for loop will have a lot of text in a single line. I think it increases readability, because if i was to replace a,b,c,d,e,f,g, with struct1->var i would have to make 2 lines or more to calculate arr[i] etc.

Secondly i think it might increase performance, because i wouldn't need to dereference these pointers in every iteration of for loop. I don't know if the loop will be 10000 iterations or 100000 in future.

I think this solution increases readability and performance. The performance boost might not even be noticeable, but i do it in order to improve readability in crucial part of the function. In my real program the var1, var2 etc. have longer names. For example they have such names as: bandwidthFactor, centralFrequency.

Since i am not very experienced programmer i would like to ask if what i have assumed is correct. Am i right to do it this way or should i not make new variables and use struct->var1 syntax to calculate arr[i] values. 
It might seem more elegant to me, but what really matters is what is more elegant to people who might see such code in a future.

Comment: `#define PI 3.14` = very funny shaped circle.

Comment: `pow(b,2.0)`, you serious? What's wrong with `b * b`?

Comment: I just did it in case someone wanted to copy paste the code. I have some macro, which supports more accurate PI value in IDE :P.
In my real code b is named bandwidthFactor. Therefore b * b is bandwidthFactor * bandwidthFactor. I prefer to  use pow(bandwidthFactor, 2) instead

Comment: @Bathsheba You can send a rocket on the moon with 3.14 ;)

Comment: @Shrouded: Well, you shouldn't. pow(x, y) can go off for surprisingly small argument values: it's often implemented as exp(y log x).

Comment: @Bathsheba I will keep that in mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Performance-wise, I think this is a micro-optimization. For readability, I think it's a win, especially since you included the `const`.  You can of course also factor out common things from the five expressions, that might be a performance win too.